# Spring-boot 2 missing logs

Tags: spring-boot, logging

We have recently migrated from SpringBoot 1.5.x to 2.0.4.RELEASE and our logging levels were missing after the change.

This is our dependencies

```
    <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR1</spring-cloud.version>   
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
        <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and this is our application.properties:

```
spring.application.name=demo

# ---------------------
# Server Configuration
# ---------------------
server.servlet.context-path=/demo
server.port=8080

# ----------------------
# Logging Level Settings
# ----------------------


app.log.level=INFO


logging.level.com.demo.service.LogMeService=DEBUG
```

Here's part of our logback.xml

```
<property file="application.properties"/>
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <File>demo-application.log</File>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <FileNamePattern>demo-application.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</FileNamePattern>
        <maxFileSize>250MB</maxFileSize>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>



<root level="${app.log.level:-INFO}">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```

The interesting part is, if we use application.properties as property filename, I can see logs of my LogMeService. Everything works fine.

But if i rename property file, say demo.properties, the logs of LogMeService is gone. Anyone else encounter this?

This only happened when we migrated to SpringBoot 2.x

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot by default takes `application.properties` as the source of configuration. Hence your log configurations are identified by the application. If you want to use another property file as the default configuration source, you could change `spring.config.location` when running the application.

```
java -jar springboot-application.jar --spring.config.location=path/to/demo.properties
```

Or else you could set the `SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION` environment variable to point to `demo.properties`.

For more information, please refer the [Spring Boot configuration guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-change-the-location-of-external-properties).

Comment: Has it changed for spring 2.x? This setup works perfectly in spring 1.5 without the need to set environment variable or setting any config location